# Shiny IO Account Info SLL Error

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to publish an app on Shiny. I have been able to do this on my home computer but not my work computer for some reason.

```
install.packages('shiny')
install.packages('devtools')
install.packages('httr')
install.packages('rsconnect')
library(shiny)
library(devtools)
library(httr)
library(rsconnect)

httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='name', token='token', secret='secret')

ui = fluidPage(
   sliderInput(inputId = "num",
          label = "Choose a number",
          value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
   plotOutput("hist")
)

server = function(input, output){
   output$hist = renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$num))
   })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Timing stopped at: 0.04 0 1.81
```

I have looked at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html but this is a over my head from a technical perspective.